# How to change a .msi installer's extraction folder?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, temporary-files

I have a .msi installer that needs 3 gigs in the C drive, to unpack (I assume). My *%TEMP%* and *%TMP%* are on a different volume, so the space needed should be there.

Does anyone know an easy way to change the unpack path?

Note: I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually extract the `*.msi` file with;

`msiexec /a <name>.msi TARGETDIR=<path> /qb`

Comment: I tried this. It only filled up my memory without any output.

Comment: It extracts silently due to /q flag, check the target directory.

Comment: I tried with /a but I get that the installer doesn't support advertise. Then I tried with /i and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can first extract the contents of the msi to a temp folder, then run it from there:

```
msiexec /a [path to my.msi] TARGETDIR=d:\temp
```